# Keep rows connected to a linked column on a separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I tried to hunt for this answer, but couldn't find my issue. Hoping this community might be able to help.

I have a sheet with a bunch of data. All sortable. Several of the columns I wanted to dynamically link to another sheet so I could add a different type of date. One for Estimates and one for Invoices, but using the project naming info from the estimate sheet. I've done this through Past Special, Paste Link feature. It works great. It auto copies over new data and even copies the sorting arrangement from one sheet to another.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet. [SAMPLE WORKBOOK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/571ulfufxjodkah/Linking%20rows%20sample%20book.xlsx?dl=0)

Sheet one is titled 'Estimates' and has a table of sortable data.

Sheet two is titled 'Invoices' and the first two rows are pasted links to the Estimates sheet. I linked the data so that as new projects are added the second sheet updates automatically. The rest of the data is invoice numbers.

The trouble comes on when I sort the data on the 'Estimates' sheet. It sorts the first two columns in the 'Invoices' sheet, but rows C through G stay static. So if you could easily misinterpret the data if you don't have the 'Estimates' sheet organized correctly.

Any way to get all the rows on the 'Invoices' sheet to track with the pasted linked columns from the 'Estimates' sheet?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Comment: So basically you wan't to connect two tables which can change in order, right? If you approach it as a database with two tables, you need to have one column in both tables with the same data. Project # makes most sense. If you have that static in both, you can use the VLOOKUP formula to get Project name automatically. I understand that this requires you to add Project # yourself to both tables, but you won't have to use VBA.

Comment: Why do you have two worksheets at all? You could add the data in Worksheet1 in different columns of worksheet2. And hide/unhide columns if necessary.

Comment: @AlexdeJong - Having a static column would work, but wouldn't that stop me from being able to sort the rows? I'd like to keep that feature if possible.

Comment: @simple-solution - That is probably the simplest solution, but not what my team would like. The actual sheets are fairly deep in columns and rows. Adding the two together would be a crazy big spreadsheet, and even hiding, unhiding would be a chore. Plus keeping the sheets separate allows departments to focus quickly on just their section without all the clutter. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @Ian No, because if you use the vlookup formula to fetch the Project Name, it will do so based on the static column in your second sheet. If you sort the first sheet, it will still place the right project name in the second sheet, because you look it op based on the project #.